# R look up matches in a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has one column, it has almost 20,0000
df1 %>% values c(10,20,30,50)

and I have another data frame, that has multiple columns one of those columns is also values.
df2 %>% id c(24782,18741,17041,10471401)
values c(70,90,10,20,50) 
and more columns in here and this data set 50,00000 of 13 variables.
I want to see if the values column in df1 %in% in values df2, and put that in a new column in a new dataframe.

df3 <- df2 %>% 
mutate(newvalue = ifelse(df1$values %in% df2$values,1,0))

Error: Column ... must be length ... (the number of rows) or one, not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems.

1. Given that you are modifying `df2`, your order is wrong. `df1$values %in% df2$values` tells you, for each `df1$values` item, whether it is in `df2`. So the result is as long as `df1`, not `df2`. It doesn't make sense to put that information *in `df2`*, because it is a result about `df1`. You either need to add the column to `df1`, or switch the order and use `df2$values %in% df1$values` (I think this is what you want).
2. `dplyr` functions expected unquoted column names of the data frame argument. So, if you pipe `df2` into `mutate`, you *don't* use `df2$` inside that `mutate`.

Making both these corrections, you get

```
df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(newvalue = ifelse(values %in% df1$values,1,0))
```

As an extra tip, `%in%` returns a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) result. You don't need `ifelse` to convert that to 1/0, it is more efficient to use `as.integer`, for the same result.

```
df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(newvalue = as.integer(values %in% df1$values))
```

Comment: Yes thank you so so much, That worked! and thank you for the explanation!

Comment: If it works well, it would be helpful for others if you tick it. Thanks